# Filter on Age where people having birthday in that month

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I have a Date Parameter that i Need to use to find out how many People in our database is under 6 years old or turns 6 in the same month as Parameter.

This is my start. ( 2017-07-02 date from Parameter )

```
SELECT a.name,a.firstname,a.birthday FROM adress a 
WHERE a.birthday >= dateadd(year,-6, { d '2017-07-02'})
```

My Problem is i Need to return thoose People that turns 6 in 2011-07 also. With the Select i have atm i only get the ones who has birthday 2017-07-01 or 2017-07-02 in June.

How can i do this nicely?

Comment: I think you need `WHERE x >= y OR x=z`, where x is `a.birthday` and y is your current `dateadd(...)` and z is those who turns 6 in 2011-07 ?

Comment: Instead of taking the the exact date parameter, use LAST_DAY('2017-07-02') and then get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, Thanks

```
SELECT a.name,a.firstname,a.birthday FROM adress a 
WHERE a.birthday >= dateadd(year,-6, EOMONTH({ d '2017-07-02'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 SELECT a.NAME, 
        a.firstname, 
        a.birthday 
 FROM   adress a 
 WHERE  Datename(mm, birthday) = Datename(mm, Getdate()) 
        AND Datename(yy, birthday) < Datename(yy, Getdate()) 
        AND Datename(dd, birthday) >= Datename(dd, Getdate())
```